# Difference between dates (years only) in boost

Tags: c++, boost

I am wondering if there is any **easy and short** approach to calculate how many years elapsed between two dates in C++ with boost?

e.g. (YYYY-MM-DD):

2005-01-01 to 2006-01-01 is 1 year

2005-01-02 to 2006-01-01 is 0 years

I can calculate it easily if I assume that there are no leap years by using such code:

```
boost::gregorian::date d1( 2005, 1, 1 );
boost::gregorian::date d2( 2006, 1, 1 );

boost::gregorian::date_duration d3 = d1 - d2;
std::cout << abs( d3.days() ) / 365;
```

but with such code the difference between 2000-01-02 and 2001-01-01 is 1 year, when it should be 0, because 2000 is the leap year and I'd like to take the leap year into account.

// EDIT

I'd like to have the year as an integer. I have created such code (which is working now I think), but still if somebody has better knowledge about boost than me, I would be grateful for some elegant solution:

```
boost::gregorian::date d1( 2005, 4, 1 );
boost::gregorian::date d2( 2007, 3, 1 );

int _yearsCount = abs( d1.year() - d2.year() );

// I want to have d1 date earlier than d2
if( d2 < d1 ) {
    boost::gregorian::date temp( d1 );
    d1 = boost::gregorian::date( d2 );
    d2 = temp;
}

// I assume now the d1 and d2 has the same year
// (the later one), 2007-04-01 and 2007-03-1
boost::gregorian::date d1_temp( d2.year(), d1.month(), d1.day() );
if( d2 < d1_temp )
    --_yearsCount;
```

Comment: Do you need 2.75461 years? Or do you need "about 3 years"? The problem with the first one is that you can't get back exact number of days unless you know the original range, so it is kinda useless. Might as well divide by 365.25 and be done with it.

Comment: I figured that the number of *full* years is needed - i.e., an integer. @tobi, please clarify!

Comment: Hey, I have edited the post, thanks for interesting.

Comment: So, does it mean (2000-02-28) - (2001-02-27) is 1 year, but (2000-03-28) - (2001-03-27) is 0 years?

Comment: @Eugene both are 0 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the number of full years (0, 1, or more), how about:

```
if (d1 > d2)
    std::swap(d1, d2); // guarantee that d2 >= d1

boost::date_time::partial_date pd1(d1.day(), d1.month());
boost::date_time::partial_date pd2(d2.day(), d2.month());

int fullYearsInBetween = d2.year() - d1.year();
if (pd1 > pd2)
    fullYearsInBetween -= 1;
```

Though this is basically equal to your algorithm (you edited the post while I was writing this).